# Will my Conroe 2.4 gig winXP work with elementry OS (The first Intel Core 2 Duo branded processor cores, code-named Conroe)

Tags: software-installation

Will my Conroe 2.4 gig winXP work with elementry OS (The first Intel Core 2 Duo branded processor cores, code-named Conroe). I would like to do a reformat / clean install of a Linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should, but however you might want to test elementary OS via a key USB before formatting your hard disk.

Comment: It should indeed, I have tested Elementary OS on several Core2Duos. The one thing to do to help is disable the animations. ---  System Settings > Universal Access > General > Disable Animations